# SearchBar with UITableViewController contains wrong amount of cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am setting up a `UISearchController` in my `UITableViewController` like this.

```
    self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.resultSearchController.delegate = self
    self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
```

In my `willPresentSearchController` I am counting the amount of cells and putting them into an array in order to make the filtered cells equal to the original ones.

```
{
    print("Will Present")
    cells.removeAll()
    print(numberOfSectionsInTableView(table))
    // Iterate over all the rows of a section
    for (var row = 0; row < tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0); row++) {
        if let cell:chatUebersichtCell = table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)) as? chatUebersichtCell{

        cells.append(cell)

        }
    }


}
```

Now, counting the cells, I am able to get a number equal to the visible amount of cells I am having in my TVC, but not more (5 on iPhone 5).

Any ideas, how to change this?

**Edit**:

NumberOfSections = 1
NumberOfRows is equal to number of cells (10 in my example)
After Row nr.5 I cannot cast to my cell anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting only 5 cells is because you are using the same view controller to present your results (the table view gets altered after the search). In order to achieve what you are looking for, you can do one of two things:

1. Keep a reference of the number of rows *before* the search happens and run your loop against this number.

OR

2. Use another table view controller for displaying your search results: `self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: newTableViewController)`

Comment: tried the first idea: Result is, that I can't cast the cells.

Comment: Second is not doing it either. I cannot count more than the 5 cells.

Comment: Can you post the code for the class with the search controller in it? @JVS

Comment: Note, that my tableViewController is not altered when I am doing the cells search. (I am putting my code into willPresent....)